# Typecast error while binding in ninject framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject.web.mvc

I'm new to Dependency Injection and also the book using recommends ninjectKernel as DI framework, [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242361) is referenced here . I am getting an error in following method:

```
 protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return controllerType == null
                ? null
                : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }
```

It throws

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'SportsStore.Domain.Concrete.EmailSettings'.

This was working totally fine until it did add the binding (below) to it.

```
private void AddBindings() {

    ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductsRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();

    EmailSettings emailSettngs = new EmailSettings {
        WriteAsFile = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager
            .AppSettings["Email.WriteAsFile"] ?? "false")
    };

    ninjectKernel.Bind<IOrderProcessor>()
        .To<EmailOrderProcessor>()
        .WithConstructorArgument("settings", "emailSettings");
}
```

**Can you give me some hints here?**

This is stack trace:

> [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'SportsStore.Domain.Concrete.EmailSettings'.]
>      DynamicInjectorc4f1546a04fc4966a278bd8198a4edff(Object[] ) +123
>      Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) +884
>      Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope) +218
>      Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +277
>      Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__f(IBinding binding) +86
>      System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +145
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4059897
>      Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) +169
>      Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) +747
>      Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) +269
>      Ninject.Activation.Providers.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2(ITarget target) +69
>      System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +66
>      System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +323
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +77
>      Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) +847
>      Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope) +218
>      Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +277
>      Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__f(IBinding binding) +86
>      System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +145
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +191
>      Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, IParameter[] parameters) +70
>      SportsStore.WebUI.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) in c:\dev\aspnet\Workout\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\Infrastructure\NinjectControllerFactory.cs:26
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +193
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6() +31
>      System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +98
>      System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +2019
>      System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +76
>      System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +28
>      System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +19
>      System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) +477
>      System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName) +34
>      ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\dev\aspnet\Workout\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:12
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
>      System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +96
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +88
>      System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +233
>      System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +71
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +64
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +246
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +95
>      System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +259
>      System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +294
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.b__17() +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +175
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +89
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9690172
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing in a string to the constructor arguments instead of the `emailSettings` object. Un-string `emailSettings`.

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IOrderProcessor>()
    .To<EmailOrderProcessor>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("settings", emailSettings);
```

Comment: you are absolutely right. I even had a typo on this line `code` EmailSettings emailSettngs = new EmailSettings {  `code`  just fixed it and works fine!  THANK YOU!